# Capistrano symlinking problem?

Tags: capistrano, symlink

I've this capistrano command.

```
  task :symlink_shared do
        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/config/database.yml"
        run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/config/app_config.yml"
        run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/app_config.yml #{release_path}/config/app_config.yml"

        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/public/records"
        run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/uploads/records #{release_path}/public/records"
        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/public/documents"
        run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/uploads/documents #{release_path}/public/documents"
        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/public/pdf_xmls"
        run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/uploads/pdf_xmls #{release_path}/public/pdf_xmls"
        run "rm -rf  #{current_path}/public/pdf_xml_files"
        run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/uploads/pdf_xml_files #{release_path}/public/pdf_xml_files"
    end
```

Everything works and the symlinks are also created.
But the last command symlink creates the symlink pdf_xml_files one step inside.
i.e. it creates a directory named pdf_xml_files and inside it, the pdf_xml_files symlink is created.
Need some help??

Comment: Can you print out current_path, shared_path, and release_path before the link is created and edit your answer with the results?

Comment: Here is the pastie of the above ran cap task.
http://pastie.org/426393

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the /home/deploy/weddingcards/releases/20090325105337/public/pdf_xml_files directory already exists.

The ln command is finding that directory and forcing it to create a symlink to your target inside the directory.

If you remove /home/deploy/weddingcards/releases/20090325105337/public/pdf_xml_files then run the same command it should do what you want it to.

Alternately you could change the command to:

```
run "ln -nsf #{shared_path}/uploads/pdf_xml_files #{release_path}/public/"
```

and it will create the symlink inside the public directory.

Comment: I'll check this and reply later.